# How to share image on twitter using react-share in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-share

I am not able to share image on twitter using react-share. My code is :

```
<TwitterShareButton 
     url={window.location.href} 
     title={props.data.breadcrumb}
     imageURL={props.data.product_info.image_path}
     children={<TwitterIcon size={32} round={true} />}
/>
```

image is being loaded from api.
i have changed imageURL to media and it is still not working.
Can i share image or not?

Comment: are you using a library/package ?

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you could share this as a base64 url from this response https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share/issues/119 which is pretty cool and easy.

So basically set the url prop:

```
url: "data:image/png;base64,<base64_data>"
```